# How do I cause iTunes to close instead of minimising when using Alt-F4?

Tags: windows, itunes

There are some badly implemented programs like iTunes that are very... difficult to close, and interpret a close command (alt-f4 or clicking the 'x') as "minimize".

Is there any setting I can change so that when I close a program it forces it to close, without having to go through the trouble of opening the task manager, find the program, kill it or clicking "close/quit" in 1000 different places hoping that one will do the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These programs use the "close to taskbar" method (stupidly, I think). If you disable this function in the program it should allow a close request, be it with alt-F4 or pressing the close button, to truly close the program.

In iTunes go to Edit -> Preferences, select the Advanced tab, uncheck the appropriate items regarding minimizing to system tray.

Answer (score 0):

For a system-wide solution, try this app:

[SuperF4](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/easily-kill-running-or-hung-processes-with-super-f4-windows/)

By default, Alt + F4 will ask the program to gracefully close.  With this tiny app, pressing Control + Alt + F4 will trigger the app to force close the process, no matter what the program is, how it is configured, or even what it is doing!  *Be careful however; as this will force close the application without allowing it to finish what it was doing, without saving what you were working on, etc.*